# How to track rows (by id) with a specific column value using Kafka JDBC Connector?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have a table containing a large number of records. There's a column defining a type of the record. I'd like to collect records with a specific value in that column. Kind of:

```
Select * FROM myVeryOwnTable WHERE type = "VERY_IMPORTANT_TYPE"
```

What I've noticed I can't use `WHERE` clause in a custom query when I choose incremental(+timestamp) mode, otherwise I'd need to take care if filtering on my own. 
The background of that I'd like to achieve is that I use Logstash to transfer some type of data from MySQL to ES. That's easily achievable there by using query that can contain where clause. However, with Kafka I can transfer my data much quicker (almost instantly) after inserting new rows in DB.

Thank you for any hints or advices.

---

Thanks to @wardziniak I was able to set it up.

```
query=select * from (select * from myVeryOwnTable p where type = 'VERY_IMPORTANT_TYPE') p
topic.prefix=test-mysql-jdbc-
incrementing.column.name=id
```

however, I was expecting a topic `test-mysql-jdbc-myVeryOwnTable` so I've registered my consumer to that. However, using the query shown above table name is skipped so my topic was named exactly as prefix defined above. So I've just updated my properties `topic.prefix=test-mysql-jdbc-myVeryOwnTable` and it seems to be working just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use subquery in your Jdbc Source Connector `query` property.

Sample JDBC Source Connector configuration:

```js
{
    ...
    "query": "select * from (select * from myVeryOwnTable p where type = 'VERY_IMPORTANT_TYPE') p",
    "incrementing.column.name": "id",
    ...
}
```

Comment: That's clever. I'll try that! Thanks

Comment: sorry that does not work. As I see it runs 
`WHERE `id` > ? ORDER BY `id` ASC`

but should:
`WHERE p.id > ? ORDER BY p.id ASC`

Just guessing, obviously, but I think that's the issue here.

Comment: @user007, Are you sure it doesn't work (records are not filter during polling from DB)? Are there any exception or errors? .I've made test and its filtering properly. I can see something like that in logs `prepared SQL query: select * from (select * from myVeryOwnTable p where type = 'VERY_IMPORTANT_TYPE') p WHERE "id" > ? ORDER BY "id"`

Comment: yes I can see that:
`[2019-04-07 21:03:31,648] INFO Cluster ID: w15JXkZYRu68ZPyJ4JFplw (org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata:365)
[2019-04-07 21:03:31,660] INFO Begin using SQL query: select * FROM (select * from mydb.mytable ev WHERE ev.type = 10) ev WHERE "id" > ? ORDER BY "id" ASC (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier:140)
[2019-04-07 21:04:31,549] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=test-source-mysql-jdbc-autoincrement-0} Committing offsets (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:398)`
but that does not return any records to my consumer.

Comment: @user007, make sure that there are _new_ records in table with bigger incremental value.  JDBC Connector keeps information regarding last incremented value, so for resetting you have to delete those information (for standalone mode remove/tmp/connect.offsets) or  create connector with new name.

Comment: @wardzininiak found it! I've registered my consumer to a topic named as "prefix-<table_name>" (prefix from my config). However, a query on subquery seems does not have any reference to any table. I've listed my topics and I've noticed a topic named as my prefix! So ... I've connected to it. And boom.... getting all results as I wanted to have. Thank you mate! That helped me A LOT.